# Second then function run before the first one in promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

This is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var printMsg = function (msg) {
    console.log("printMsg: " + msg)
};

var myWrite = function (filename, content) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fs.writeFile(filename, content, function (err) {
            console.log("content: " + content);
            if (err || content.includes('Fail')) {
               console.log("promise rejected for content: '" + content + "'");
               reject("error writing");
            }
            else {
               console.log("promise resolved for content: '" + content + "'");
               resolve("ok");
            }
        });
    });
};

myWrite("test.txt", "Hello world")
    .then(myWrite("test.txt", "Failed"))
    .then(myWrite("test.txt", "How are you?"))
    .catch(printMsg);
```

In this example, I was expected that things will happening in this order:

1. The log will print the content "Hello world"
2. The function resolved it with "ok".
3. The log will print the content "Failed"
4. The function rejected it with "error writing" message.
5. The next promise will be skipped.
6. The catch will execute the second promise with the message "error writing"

The actual result was very confusing, all the promises ran async and all the promises executed without the catch function.

Output:

```
content: Hello world
promise resolved for content: 'Hello world'
content: How are you?
promise resolved for content: 'How are you?'
content: Failed
promise rejected for content: 'Failed'
```

The output changed from time to time and can be also:

```
content: How are you?
promise resolved for content: 'How are you?'
content: Hello world
promise resolved for content: 'Hello world'
content: Failed
promise rejected for content: 'Failed'
```

If I moved the log of the content before the "writeFile" function, it will log all the content names first in async order, which mean that all the promises executed together.
Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong?

Thank's!

Comment: `.then` accepts a function as an argument, not the result of calling a function - i.e. in this case you are passing a promise to `.then` - a promise isn't a function

Comment: preface the calls in `.then` with `() =>` and stand back and watch

Comment: Jaromanda X, Thank you very much!:) I really didn't know this..